# Dynamic Nav menu with $_GET php

Tags: php

i have a navigation menu and using  $_GET[] to display dynamic sublinks to navigation menu. How do i keep the number from adding even more than one a,b or c? when it has been clicked once.

```
<li><a href="?p=1">Link 1<a/>
echo $output;
</li>
<li><a href="?p=2">Link 2<a/>
echo $output;
</li>

<li><a href="?p=3">Link 3<a/>
echo $output;
</li>

$page_id = $_Get['p'];

if (($page_id ==1) OR($page_id==2) OR ($page_id==3)){
$output='<li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'a">sublink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'b">sublink 2</a></li>
<li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'c">sublink 3</a></li>';
```

}

what i want to achive is ?p=1,2 or 3 will stay at ?=1a at top and when a second sublink is clicked it will shift to ?p=1b from ?p=1a for example. atm it works like ?p=1 first link will be ?p=1a and when a second sublink is pressed it will go to ?p=1ab. how to prevent this?

At the moment i use

```
  if ($page_id ==1){
$output='<li><a href="?p=1a">sublink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=1b">sublink 2</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=1c">sublink 3</a></li>';

}
if ($page_id==2){
$output='<li><a href="?p=2a">sublink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=2b">sublink 2</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=2c">sublink 3</a></li>';

}
if ($page_id==3){
$output='<li><a href="?p=3a">sublink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=3b">sublink 2</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=3c">sublink 3</a></li>';

}
```

Sloved the problem by using **substr**

```
if ($page_id==1) OR ($page_id==2) OR ($page_id==3)){
$subpage = $_GET['p'];
$subpage = substr($subpage,0,1);
$output = <li><a href="'.$subpage.'a">Link 1</a></li>
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on the end result you want

Comment: i edited my post to better explain what i want to achive here. i hope it explains good enought to be usefull info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?php
$output = array();
$page_id = isset($_GET['p'])? intval($_GET['p']) : '1';
if (($page_id ==1) OR($page_id==2) OR ($page_id==3)){

   $output[$page_id]= '<li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'a">sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'b">sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="?p='.$page_id.'c">sublink 3</a></li>';

}?>

<ul>
<li><a href="?p=1">Link 1<a/>
<?php echo isset($output[1]) ? $output[1] : '';?>
</li>
<li><a href="?p=2">Link 2<a/>
<?php echo isset($output[2]) ? $output[2] : ''; ?>
</li>

<li><a href="?p=3">Link 3<a/>
<?php echo isset($output[3]) ? $output[3] : '';?>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the repetition problem is solved. Hope this is what you require.

Comment: Yeah but i came up with another solution using substr($string,0,1) by limit it to 1 before using page_id agian and this fixed the problem i had.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go with a second $_GET Parameter? This would be a much cleaner aproarch.

As Example:

```
$page=intval($_GET['p']);
if(isset($_GET['subpage'])){
    $subpage=htmlspecialchars($_GET['subpage']);
}
```

This way you would avoid your problem and also have a much cleaner code.

Also you should take a code into [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), since your code
is vulnerable.

Comment: im not following you here in this ex, could you explain it better? im aware of the security flaws. i mean how to stop increase from it´s clicked once.

Comment: Use a second parameter from the subpage. As example:
<a href="?p=<?=$_GET['p]?>&sp=<?=$_GET['sp']?">Link Current</a>